# Chrome theme bug Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I got this button to switch themes:

```
public void onButtonThemeActionEvent(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {


        if(index == 0) {
            index++;
            UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Leather");
            Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
            }
            else if(index == 1) {
                index++;
                UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Chrome");
                Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
            }
            else if(index == 2) {
                index++;
                UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "FlatOrange");
                Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
            }
            else if(index == 3) {
                index++;
                UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "FlatBlue");
                Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
            }
            else if(index == 4) {
                index++;
                UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "FlatRed");
                Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
            }
            else if(index == 5) {
                index = 0;
                UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Business");
                Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
            }
    }
```

This code will change the themes in a sequence as you can see, the problem happens when changing from Leather to Chrome then as you can see in the image below in the Form title is missing a letter "Tela Princip**a**" it should be "Tela Princip**al**" instead.

**OBS: This is an Android Device.**

Chrome theme missing a letter in the Form title:
[image: Missing a letter in the Form title]

After navigating through any menu and backing to Tela Principal, it is fixed as in the following image:

[image: fixed after navigating through menus]

How to fix this Chrome theme bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `revalidate()` after switching themes so the UI will update to new font sizes/padding/margin etc.

If that doesn't work try a `forceRevalidate()` which you shouldn't normally do but is sometimes necessary.

Comment: Have you tried to call the Form.show() again after the theme change?

Comment: In the `init(Object)` method try `Toolbar.setCenteredDefault(false)`